# G1 Garbage Collector: Why survivor space is -1

Tags: java, spring-boot, garbage-collection, g1gc, java-17

I see these metrics:

```
# HELP jvm_memory_max_bytes The maximum amount of memory in bytes that can be used for memory management
# TYPE jvm_memory_max_bytes gauge
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space",} -1.0
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen",} 8.05306368E8
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 2.01326592E8
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeCache",} 1.34217728E8
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space",} -1.0
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 3.3554432E7
```

I don't understand why i see `-1` ?

`Nomad` Settings:

```
   jvm:
      ReservedCodeCache: 128
      CompressedClassSpace: 32
      ThreadsCount: 100
      MetaSpace: 64
      MaxMetaSpace: 192
      Xss: 256 
      flags: >-
        -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
        -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
        -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary 
        -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics 
        -XX:+UseG1GC 
        -XX:+UseCompressedOops 
        -verbose:sizes
        -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
    java_xmx: 768
    extra_memory: 50
```

This happend when migrated to java 17, before on java 8 all metrics were valid and not `-1`.

Comment: You’re only wondering about the `-1` but not the use of floating point values for memory sizes? Interpretation 1: “minus one means ‘No Limit’”. Interpretation 2: “An unsigned max long has been interpreted as signed value”. Both boil down to the same effective result.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. Why there is no limit? Is this a good thing? How Can i set it? Should i set it?

Comment: These areas are limited to the maximum total heap size anyway. There’s no reason to have individual maximum sizes.