# Spring Boot JVM Metrics, Why some values of jvm_memory_max_bytes is -1

Tags: jvm, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I think the problem is same as [G1 Garbage Collector: Why survivor space is -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374328/g1-garbage-collector-why-survivor-space-is-1).

But the questioner's question occurred while migrating to jdk17, my case happened on jdk8.

My /actuator/prometheus output:

```
# HELP jvm_memory_max_bytes The maximum amount of memory in bytes that can be used for memory management
# TYPE jvm_memory_max_bytes gauge
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space",} -1.0
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen",} 1.073741824E9
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} -1.0
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space",} -1.0
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Code Cache",} 2.5165824E8
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 1.073741824E9
```

What's the meaning of -1? Why did this happen?

Comment: And comments from linked question about this being unlimited don't satisfy you why?

Comment: Is there something wrong there? Why 'G1 Eden Space', 'G1 Survivor Space' are no reason to have individual maximum sizes?

Comment: Any clue why this is happening?